# Sweave: use a chunk as a latex command parameter

Tags: r, latex, sweave

Is it somehow possible with Sweave to define a Latex-command
and pass the results from a chunk as parameter?

Basically I want to create something like in this example:

```
\newcommand{\myCommand} [1] {
    \begin{figure} 
      \begin{center}
        #1
      \end{center}
    \end{figure}
}

\myCommand{
   <<fig=TRUE, results=hide>>
      plot(1:10,1:10)
   @
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of a plot chunk is an includegraphics command in resulting .tex file :

```
\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{figure/testPlot}
```

So your new command should work (with corrected syntax here) : when the chunk is evaluated, the includegraphics is wrote to the .tex file. After this step, the latex code is evaluated, with all your commands and options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\myCommand} [1] {
    \begin{figure}[t] 
      \begin{center}
        #1
      \end{center}
    \end{figure}
}
\myCommand{
   <<testPlot>>=
      plot(1:10,1:10)
   @
}
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**
This solution works only with [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) :

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr);knit('myFile.Rnw')"
```

Or to produce a pdf :

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr);knit2pdf('myFile.Rnw')"
```

With Rstudio, please read this : [Weaving .Rnw using rstudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532247-Weaving-Rnw-Files?version=0.98.953&mode=desktop)

Comment: For me this solution still does not work...The generated tex-file contains the whole chunk as parameter for the latex command and not the \includegraphics command (I am using R-Studio to execute the Rnw file).

Comment: Ok. I've found something : try to sweave with knitr option : in options -> Sweave -> weave Rnw using knitr

Comment: And.. it seems that Rstudio add this line `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}` to your .Rnw if you try to weave with sweave option once.

Comment: I could reproduce your solution...thx. I guess there is no reason for using Sweave instead of knitr anyways...